# Есть ли в Java раннее связывание?

Tags: java

Модификатор `final` в Java не обеспечивает раннее связывание метода (на этапе компиляции), лишь не дает определить метод в наследнике с такой же сигнатурой и в том числе переопределить соответствующий метод предка, так ли это?

**Вопрос:** Есть ли в Java ранее связывание, то есть когда уже на этапе компиляции вызову метода ставится в соответствие код который будет выполняться?

Comment: P.s. В Java есть раннее связывание?

Comment: Что такое ранее связывание по вашему, господа программисты?

Comment: Уже на этапе компиляции вызову метода ставится в соответствие код который будет выполняться.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Цитата из источника: **[Полиморфизм в Java](http://strongexperts.narod.ru/ru/articles/archive/java2/2006/apr2006-004/apr2006-004.htm)**:

Если перегруженные методы с одинаковыми именами находятся в одном классе, списки параметров должны отличаться. Но если метод подкласса совпадает с методом суперкласса (порождающего класса), то метод подкласса переопределяет метод суперкласса. Совпадать при этом должны и имена методов и типы входных и выходных параметров. В данном случае переопределение методов является основой концепции *динамического связывания* (или *позднее связывание*), реализующей полиморфизм. Суть динамической диспетчеризации методов состоит в том, что решение на вызов переопределенного метода принимается во время выполнения, а не во время компиляции. Однако final-методы не являются переопределяемыми, их вызов может быть организован во время компиляции и [называется ранним связыванием](http://strongexperts.narod.ru/ru/articles/archive/java2/2006/apr2006-004/apr2006-004.htm).

Comment: Можно еще добавить статические методы, у них тоже раннее связывание

Comment: Еще вызовы методов через ключевое слово `super` всегда используют раннее связывание.

Answer (score -2):

`final` по самому простому привязывает переменную к значению, тем самым делая ее константой, т. е.

```
 final int  a = 0; // a всегда будет 0
```

Comment: а чем тогда отличается 
final constant int a = 0;
от
final int a = 0 
?

Comment: Тем что первый вариант даже не скомпилируется, так как ошибочный

Comment: Я спрашивал про final метод -- это совсем не то.

Comment: Если метод final, то его нельзя override, т.е. Переопределять в классах наследниках

Comment: В C# не virtual метод тоже нельзя переопределить, тем не менее ничто не мешает в наследнике реализовать такой же метод, с такой же сигнатурой.

Comment: но по-моему так делать не стоит:

    void Main()
    {
 var a = new A();
 a.Method(); // class A
 var b = new B();
 b.Method(); // class B
 A a1 = new A();
 a1.Method(); // class A
 A b1 = new B();
 b1.Method(); // class A WTF?
    }

    class A{
 public void Method()
 {
  "class A".Dump();
 }
    }
    class B:A{
 public void Method()
 {
  "class B".Dump();
 }
    }

Comment: WTF? где мой полиморфизм?))) и все-таки есть в java раннее связывание или нет?

Comment: Где-то я читал, что компилятор *может* использовать информацию типа final static для оптимизации генерируемого кода.

Comment: @avp, да такое есть, клнстанты тогда укладываются в спец блоки памяти для быстрого доступа к ним. @jan, вероятней всего, что есть, например когда ты одним методом пытаешься вернуть разные обьекты в зависимости от типа вх.  параметра

Answer (score -2):

А как же overloading?

```
public class LinkageTest {

    public static class Parent {

        public void test() {
            System.out.println("parent::test");
        }
    }

    public static class Child extends Parent {

        public void test() {
            System.out.println("child::test");
        }
    }

    public static class Tester {

        public void test(Parent obj) {
            System.out.println("Testing parent...");
            obj.test();
        }

        public void test(Child obj) {
            System.out.println("Testing child...");
            obj.test();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent obj = new Child();
        Tester t = new Tester();
        t.test(obj);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Testing parent...
child::test
```